# camel-mail IMAP not skipping failed messages

Tags: java, apache-camel, jakarta-mail, imap

I have the route "**imap://%s@%s?password=%s&folderName=%s&unseen=true&delete=true&skipFailedMessage=true**" to poll emails and skip failed ones. This property **skipFailedMessage=true** is not being honored or I am miss understanding the use of it.

I am reading emails from 5 different mailboxes with different placeholders but no emails get read when I encounter "org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: found valid base64 character after a padding character (=)" on onw of the emails. I can only read all other emails on different mail boxes if the failing message is deleted. Please help. I tried versions 2.17.3 and 2.18 and both are behaving the same way.

Here is the stack trace:

> org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to:
>   BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: found valid base64 character
>   after a padding character (=), the 10 most recent characters were:
>   "xmlns:v="u". Exchange: Exchange[]. Message:
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage@7883ab8c    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailBinding.extractBodyFromMail(MailBinding.java:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailMessage.createBody(MailMessage.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.createExchanges(MailConsumer.java:354)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException: BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded
>   stream: found valid base64 character after a padding character (=),
>   the 10 most recent characters were: "xmlns:v="u"  at
>   com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream.decode(BASE64DecoderStream.java:309)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream.read(BASE64DecoderStream.java:144)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:98)   at
>   javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:795)
>     at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:542)    at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1454)     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailBinding.extractBodyFromMail(MailBinding.java:250)
>     ... 13 common frames omitted

Comment: Add the stacktrace you see to the questions so people can better help

Comment: I logged a ticket to catch wider exceptions in the mail component: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10527

Comment: @user2215545 have you checked 2.17.5, 2.18.1, 2.19.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Claus Ibsen for logging the issue. The problem was reported fixed in version  [2.17.5, 2.18.1, 2.19.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10527)

I verified that it was fixed on version 2.18.1.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from JavaMail, probably due to an incorrectly formatted message.  You can tell JavaMail to ignore such errors by setting the System property `"mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors"` to `"true"`.